# How to access a resource / configuration / text file in an external Jar from Java?

Tags: java, jar, osgi, classloader, embedded-resource

I am running a program in *com.me.X.jar*.

In an external *com.me.Y.jar*, I have a configuration file located at '*config/conf.txt*' in the root of the Jar.

**How can I access this configuration file programmatically from within Java?**

*com.me.Y.jar* is not currently loaded in memory and is composed of just non-code resources.

Comment: Include the jar in the class path and access it as any normal embedded resource

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Could be an answer.  Should be Embedded. :)

Comment: You added an OSGi keyword, are you looking for an OSGi answer?

Answer (score 2):

jar files are just zip files. So google for an example how to read a zip file. Or have a look at the API [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option for reading embedded resources is to use `Class.getResource` or `Class.getResourceAsStream`

I can think of several ways to achieve this, depending on your needs.

Add the `com.me.Y.jar` to the classpath.  You can do this either at the system level (not really recommended) or at the commend line...

`java -cp com.me.Y.jar -jar com.me.X.jar`

**Edit**  It has being pointed at that apparently the `-cp` argument is ignored using the above command, but, if you include the main class it will work...`java -cp com.me.Y.jar -jar com.me.X.jar com.me.x.Main` (for example)

If that's inconvient, you can add `com.me.Y.jar` to `com.me.X.jar` [manifest's class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) which will automatically include `com.me.Y.jar` for you.

If you can't do that, you could use a `URLClassLoader` to directly load `com.me.Y.jar`...

```
URL[] urls = new URL[]{new File("/path/to/com.me.Y.jar").toURI().toURL())};
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
URL resource = classLoader.findResource("/config/conf.txt");
```

Or, if you prefer, you could simply crack the Jar open using [`java.util.JarFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html), but that seems a lot like cracking walnuts with a nuke...IMHO

Comment: `java -cp com.me.Y.jar -jar ..`  When `-jar` is specified, `-cp` is ignored.  Go figure.

Comment: !! Really...gee, that's nice, must be using the jar's manifest instead, bastereds

Comment: You can still specify main explicitly (& class-path).  `java -cp com.me.Y.jar com.me.X.jar com.me.X.Main`

Comment: @AndrewThompson (the only reason I use # (ie Class#getResource) is that people seem to think it's a static reference otherwise ;))

Comment: You can edit it back when you change the CLI invocation.  I always see it is an invalid docs. copy/paste.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I really should be linking to the Docs, but really, if people can't do a Google search than what hope to we have :P

Answer (score 1):

### Code to obtain URL

```
URL configURL = this.getClass().getResource("/config/conf.txt");
```

### `Manifest.mf` of `com.me.X.jar`

See [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

```
Main-Class: ...
Class-Path: com.me.Y.jar
```